# What is the correct way of using computed data that I am calc from fetched data?

Tags: vue.js

I want to write simple app that takes data from server, compute result and display it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>
<body>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ my_data }}</p>
  <div> computed value: {{myvalue}} </div>  <!-- I need to get access to myvalue from computed --> 

</div>

</body>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    my_data: {},
    mess: 'hello world'
  },
    computed: {
      myvalue: function () {
            return Number(this.my_data['2018-07-10']['april']) + Number(this.my_data['2018-07-10']['may'])
      }
    },

     created: async function(){
        url = 'http://dlang.ru/test'
        const response = await fetch(url);
        this.my_data = await response.json();
    }   
})

</script>
</html>
```

The page displays:

```
{ "2018-07-10": { "may": 9, "april": 10 } }

computed value: 19
```

But in console I am getting error: `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'april' of undefined"`

If I right understand it's trying display mustached `{{my_data}}` before server return data and computed will calculate it.

What is the right way to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're understanding the problem correctly, you have a race condition in your code because of your async created lifecycle hook, there are a couple approaches you can take to solve this problem:

1. Fetch the data before initializing the Vue app and pass it to the Vue app as a prop or
2. Check if `my_data` has been populated with data in your computed property before trying to use it.